# Reducing getter/setter boilerplate in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I often find myself writing this sort of getter/setter boilerplate:

```
private _length = 0;

get length(): number { return this._length; }
set length(value: number) { this._length = value; }
```

In C#, I know that you can write something like this:

```
public length { get; set; }
```

Is there an equivalent way to simplify my Typescript code?

Comment: I am wondering what is the point of such a getter/setter? I.e. how are they different from directly exposing the field since there's no override limitation in TypeScript? If the point is to have a read-only field, why not do it properly via property descriptor?

Comment: @billc.cn in my case I am actually adding additional functionality inside the get/set functions to trigger events on the main object when the values change.

Answer (score 7):

One way that I've found is to use decorators, which were introduced in Typescript 1.5. The implementation looks like this:

```
function prop(target: Object, name: string) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
    get: function() { return this["_" + name]; },
    set: function(value) { this["_" + name] = value; },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}
```

Now, you can replace the code in the OP with this:

```
@prop length = 0;
```

One thing to note is that a `_length` property will be added to the object. If you don't need to access it, you're good! If you do need to use it, and you want it to autocomplete, you can annotate the property like so:

```
@prop length = 0; private _length = 0;
```

Comment: +1. Also, it could be useful to separate getter and setter decorator and use them only when needed: `@get @set length = 0`, `@get id;` etc.